# Excel Link To Images

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am importing my stock items onto an online selling platform, but on the excel spreadsheet I need to put a link to the image location.

I have uploaded images to my website, what is 
https://sitebuilder.freeola.com/media/images/user-images/40137/10001.jpg

What I am wanting to do, is where it has 10001.jpg, is use some sort of code, as 10001 is my product SKU, what is also on the sheet in Row V, so that I do not have to put a link for all 500 products.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `concatenate()` command.  Then just copy the command all the way down your product listing to capture the URL's for all the SKU's.

For example you will have the following:

`Cell A1:   https://sitebuilder.freeola.com/media/images/user-images/40137/`

`Cell B1:   10001`

`Cell C1:   .jpg`

`Cell D1:  =concatenate(A1, B1, C1)`

That'll put it all together as:

`https://sitebuilder.freeola.com/media/images/user-images/40137/10001.jpg`